# Why am I losing these constructed objects with smart pointers, but not new?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I think I'm misunderstanding something about smart pointers. Take a look at the following example. When I use new/`*`, I get exactly what I expect, but when I use `std::shared_ptr`, I get a null pointer error. Isn't the smart pointer implementation equivalent to what I did with new/`*`?

Also, can I adjust `AnotherGiver` to avoid many pointer dereferences?

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
class numGiver
{
public:
    virtual int giveNum(void) = 0;
    virtual int othNum(void) = 0;
};


class constGiver : public numGiver
{
public:
    int giveNum(void)
    {
        return 5;
    }
    int othNum(void)
    {
        return 5;
    }
};


class othAddGiver : public numGiver
{
public:
    int giveNum(void)
    {
        return myNum + ng->giveNum();
    }
    int othNum(void)
    {
        return ng->othNum();
    }
    othAddGiver(std::shared_ptr<numGiver> ng, int num) : ng(ng), myNum(num) {};
private:
    std::shared_ptr<numGiver> ng;
    int myNum;
};

class AnotherGiver : public numGiver
{
public:
    int giveNum(void)
    {
        return myNum + ng->giveNum();
    }
    int othNum(void)
    {
        return ng->othNum();
    }
    AnotherGiver(numGiver* ng, int num) : ng(ng), myNum(num) {};
private:
    numGiver* ng;
    int myNum;
};


int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<numGiver> ng = std::make_shared<constGiver>();
    std::shared_ptr<numGiver> og;
    numGiver* anotherGiver = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            anotherGiver = new AnotherGiver(&*ng, 3);
            std::shared_ptr<numGiver> og = std::make_shared<othAddGiver>(ng, 3);
        }
        else
        {

            anotherGiver = new AnotherGiver(anotherGiver, 3);
            std::shared_ptr<numGiver> og = std::make_shared<othAddGiver>(og, 3);
        }

    }
    std::cout << anotherGiver->giveNum() << std::endl;
    std::cout << anotherGiver->othNum() << std::endl;
    std::cout << og->giveNum() << std::endl;
    std::cout << og->othNum() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<numGiver> og = std::make_shared<othAddGiver>(ng, 3);` you are redeclaring `og`, not assigning to the original variable.

Comment: It is because you are using three different `og` variables. You should compile with `-Wshadow` or `/W4` to make compiler warn about such things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are shadowing the outer scope's `og` with the definitions

```
std::shared_ptr<numGiver> og = std::make_shared<othAddGiver>(ng, 3);
```

and

```
std::shared_ptr<numGiver> og = std::make_shared<othAddGiver>(og, 3);
```

If you remove the `std::shared_ptr<numGiver>` from those lines, it [works fine.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/574725f8a487e497)

Comment: THANK YOU, Didn't realize I was doing something so obvious.